# How to fix CVE-2020-7663 | CVSS Score: 7.5 vulnerability

Tags: angular, security, quality-gate

I generate a new angular application. After commiting the code, SnarQube analysis indicates that quality gate is failed, because :
websocket-extensions:0.1.4 | Reference: CVE-2020-7663 | CVSS Score: 7.5 .

I read this post of :  [James Coglan, fix with 0.1.4](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2020/06/02/redos-vulnerability-in-websocket-extensions/) 
but it doesn't fix my issue.
in package-lock.json, theire is websocket-extensions with 0.1.4, then how to fix it?
below my cofiguration:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 10.16.3
OS: linux x64

Angular: 9.1.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.12
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.12
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.12
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.12
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.31
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.12
@schematics/angular               9.1.12
@schematics/update                0.901.12
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0

Also:
npm  : 6.9.0
```

Thanks for help,

Comment: Are you actually using sockets in your application..?

Comment: no, I don't use any socket

Comment: still no solution?

Comment: It sounds like a false positive. Ng serve uses a socket to auto-refresh browser during development, but this shouldn’t be there inside the production code.